# Protect URL, Arduino HTTP request

Tags: google-app-engine, arduino

I am using an Arduino Yun to make basic HTTP requests to send email messages for an alarm system.  Based on certain input, the Yun will just ping a URL like myapp.appspot.com/alarm which will trigger an email.  I don't need high security, rather I just don't want to be spammed if a web crawler or random person enters the URL.  Can I just use a long URL like: myapp.appspot.com/blah_blah_long_url_that_nobody_will_ever_guess?  I lack the web app experience to know the ramifications of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simplest way:** (and not very secure) way would be to send some secret inside the request:

1. Use HTTPS, so that the request can not be (easily) snooped and secret extracted.
2. Send a secret string in a request header that is then checked on server.

**Better way:** (but still not foolproof):

1. Always use HTTPS
2. Use secret salt (only stored inside Arduino), then hash body of the request with this salt.
3. To prevent reply attack, generate a one time ID on client, then check on server that this ID is only used once (you do store all send email requests, right?)

This is a security-through-obscurity: you are protected until someone reverses your setup and gets the salt and protocol.

**Best way:** (in given case, but not 100% secure):

1. Create your own certificate (self-signed is ok) and use [custom SSL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl)
2. Use this certificate in Arduino to connect to server (if possible)